# for i in -loop with Entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter

Trying to get hand of tkinter, widgets and neighboring areas.
Keep getting an error - and after hours of googling, not answers pop up.

For some reason this loop shows all of the filenames in the entry-line - rather than one at a time... - what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for helping out !

```
    __author__ = 'Orphan Black'

import os
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *
import time

class PermFrame(Frame):

    def __init__ (self, master):
        super(PermFrame, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.createLable()


        menu = Menu()
        self.master.config(menu=menu)


        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Settings", command=self.setting_menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)


        about = Menu(menu)
        about.add_command(label="Info")
        menu.add_cascade(label="About", menu=about)

        self.enpath_label = Label(self, text = "Enter path: ")
        self.enpath_label.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.path_ent = Entry(self, width=52)
        self.path_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.sub_bttn = Button(self, text = "Check", command = self.submit_path)
        self.sub_bttn.grid(row = 2, column = 4, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.run_bttn = Button(self, text = "Run", command = self.run_prg)
        self.run_bttn.grid(row = 2, column = 5, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.orgfn_label = Label(self, text = "Original name: ")
        self.orgfn_label.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.org_filename = Text(self, width=37, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
        self.org_filename.grid(row=4, column = 3, columnspan = 5, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.newfn_label = Label(self, text = "New name: ")
        self.newfn_label.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.new_filename = Text(self, width=37, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
        self.new_filename.grid(row=5, column = 3, columnspan = 5, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.constxt_label = Label(self, text = "Console ")
        self.constxt_label.grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=0)


        self.console_txt = ScrolledText(self, width=71, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.console_txt.grid(row=7, column = 2, columnspan = 4, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=0)

    def submit_path(self):
        # console = console
        time_date = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        contents = self.path_ent.get()
        message = ("\n{}: Trying {}...".format(time_date, contents))
        self.console_txt.insert(END, message)
        try:
            os.chdir(contents)
            msgok = ("\n{}: The path {}, is valid".format(time_date, contents))
            prg_start = ("\n{}: Program starting...".format(time_date, contents))
            self.console_txt.insert(END, msgok)

        except (ValueError, RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, FileNotFoundError):
            notok_mssg= ("\n{}: The path you entered is not valid...Enter a new path".format(time_date))
            self.console_txt.insert(END,notok_mssg,)

    def run_prg(self):
        os.listdir(self.path_ent.get())

        for file in os.listdir(self.path_ent.get()):
            #print(file)
            self.org_filename.insert(END,(file))
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the class, or at least the header and `__init__`?

Comment: yes, I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want your entry widget to display the contents of `os.listdir` one at a time as you iterate over it changing the entry widgets value upon each iteration.

But, as you're iterating you keep inserting things into the entry widget at the last index in the Entry widget. You never delete the Entry widget's contents so you just see this is one big mesh of text.

Sticking with the Entry widget... you can do this:

```
self.org_filename.delete(0, END) #Could also use "end" instead of END
#insert new text
```

If all you want is this updating text behavior, then you should really just use a label. With a label it's easier.

```
some_label['text'] = new_filename
```

**Additional notes:**

Don't override keywords

You should use a name other than `file` in your forloop. It's a built-in keyword. Whenever you do this you're overriding functionality.

Don't use import *

With small scripts, it's not much of an issue, but as you start expanding your programs it becomes very easy to have clashing imports / unexpected behavior and in general it becomes a lot harder to keep track of things / debug.

e.g. - If we did `import tkinter as some_name` and we used `some_name.*` where `*` would be anything from tkinter you wanted to use such as tk.END as above, or even the widget classes it' a lot easier to keep track of. We know *exactly* where everything comes from.

Blocking Tk's main event loop

If you have a large directory then iterating like this will block Tk's main event loop. Consider using a separate thread instead.

Comment: You are abolsutly right. I did not "clean" from last entry. Thank you so much ! Also, thank you for the hints. Still very new to python...and programming.